# Any way to convert class library function into exe?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Is there any way to change my class library program into an `.exe` or a *click once*-application? It is Currently a dll.

I am able to create a click once app but it is not working after installation.

Comment: create a exe project and include ur dll

Comment: Properties -> Output Type -> Change from Class Library.  However, there will be a few more steps you'll have to take; probably easier to just start as a console app or windows forms app and add your code.

Comment: I rolled back this question to its first revision since the question was altered too much. I do not think that the edit button was created in order to circumvent issues with creating new questions.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the properties of the project -> application tag, change the Output type to console Application. Anyway, you need to create a `static Main()` method as a starting point.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 16):

You can change the output type of your project in it's settings, then add a main entrypoint, as others have mentioned (Note, you want "Windows application", not "Console Application" here):

[image]

If you can't change the source for some reason, you can create a new very simple application (an .exe), and call public methods in your .dll from it:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    internal class YourApp
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Call your function here. 
        }
    }
}
```

To do this, you just need to include a reference to the existing .dll into this new application.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than *changing* it to an EXE - create a new project (Winform App, WPF, Console App, whatever) and *reference* your DLL to use the classes from it.

If you convert your DLL to an EXE then you lose (or at least significantly hinder) the ability to use those classes in any other application.

Keep non-UI classes in a DLL and only put UI-layer classes and controls in the executable.

Answer (score 0):

Within dotnet core, just add this to the `csproj`, ideally within the first `PropertyGroup`:

`<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>`

Just watch out if your target framework was `netstandard`, that of course will not work (!).