# How do I create an .exe file in Visual Studio?

Tags: vb.net, basic

I cant wrap my head around this. If I try to build I just get a dll, but I want a exe!

Comment: Do you want a [console app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/quickstart-visual-basic-console?view=vs-2019)?  Otherwise, there are templates for Web applications, Desktop applications, etc.

Comment: Or, you can [change an existing project type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16237097/3791245) to be an application (exe) instead of a library (dll) in the project's settings.  But you still need to decide what _kind_ of application you want.

Comment: I want a Windows Forms app. How would I use those templates?

Comment: In Visual Studio, start a "New Project", and select the "Windows Forms App" template" from the list.  Filter on "VB.Net", "Windows" and "Desktop"

Comment: Please be aware that, if you're using the latest version of VS 2019, then there are two project templates for a VB Windows Forms App. If you didn't even choose one of them in the first place, I'm not sure you'd be paying enough attention to notice that there are two. One will target .NET Framework, which is version 4.8 or earlier. The other is just labelled ".NET", which will target .NET 5.0 by default. That latter option is .NET Core. There are reasons not to use the latest .NET Core version but be aware that, if you target .NET Framework, you can't easily migrate to .NET Core later.

Answer (score 4):

If you have created a project using type *Class Library*, you will get a *dll*. Try creating a new project of type, for example, *Windows Form App*. When you compile it, you will end up with an *exe* file.

The [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/tutorial-projects-solutions) has all the info you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Advanced Installer" to create a .exe or .msi installer that creates a .exe launcher. I hope this helped!